# getProgramAccounts - error when calling

Tags: rpc, python, error, node, endpoint

Good day to all.
I encountered this problem.
When I call getProgramAccounts I don't get a response but an error.

1. Tell me, maybe I’m doing something wrong?
2. My task is to get a list of tokens - am I doing it right?

I'm calling the endpoint via Python.
I tried through a free node and through the main point, but as you can see the result is bad (in the console on the screenshots)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most rpcs rate-limit `GPA` calls or always return an error(if the results aren't already cached) because it's relatively expensive. Consulting your rpc provider support or consider switching.